# Downloading older versions of Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, 10.04

I need to get Ubuntu 10.04 version. Where can I find it online?

Comment: Please read the FAQ before posting next time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an old unsupported release.  10.04 is still supported as a server till April 2015 but desktop support ended in May 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You will find old releases by following [this link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/).

Answer (score 1):

You won't get software or updates for Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop or any other unsupported release as per canonical policies.

However, Ubuntu 10.04 server will be supported till 2015 can be downloaded from http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

check this for support details

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_10.04_Lucid_Lynx#Version_end_of_life